# How to replace Basic auth with Spring Boot security feature?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Currently we are using Basic auth and setting username and password in encrypted format to HttpHeaders. Is there any way to remove/replace this with any Springboot security? If yes, can you help me to implement this in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Can you follow the step to remove existing basic-auth from spring
  boot
- In spring boot we can enable BasicAuth by configuring utility class
  which WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, And when you configured it, You
  will allow to get authenticated prior to accessing any configured URL
  (or all urls) In your application.

**Steps**

1. You have to remove WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extended class

I will attach How it is look likes

```
@Configuration
public class EnablingSecutiry extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
         .csrf().disable()
         .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
         .and()
         .httpBasic();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin")
            .password("{noop}password")
            .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

**Steps**

2. Remove dependency from POM file

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```